# WPF Xaml Access Custom control in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I have a custom control `AutoCompleteTextBox in a DataTemplate as shown below:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                Margin="5" />

        <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Padding="2">

            <uc:AutoCompleteTextBox x:Name="AutoTextBox" />

        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```

How can i Access `AutoTextBox` in code Behind?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access controls in a DataTemplate directly by name! But you could try getting down the VisualTree...

```
DependencyObject dgColumnHeader = GetYourColumnHeader();
var yourAutoCompleteTextBox = FindVisualChild<AutoCompleteTextBox>(dgColumnHeader);


public static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        if (child != null && child is T)
            return (T)child;
        else
        {
            T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```